# Perl Loop only once

Tags: perl

For some reason i can not get this to loop once through it keeps doing it three times.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $argument_value (@ARGV){
   my $length = @ARGV;
   if ($length < 3){
      print "Invalid command line arguments to program. Please supply two or more strings to sort."
   } else {
      print join (" ", @ARGV);
   }
}
```

Comment: You loop over the arguments. If you give two arguments, plus the 0 argument, what do you expect?

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is, but if you do not want to loop, then remove the `for my $argument_value (@ARGV){` and the last `}`. Then report whether it acts closer to what you want, please.

Comment: Did you try? Please give feedback by writing a comment to your own question (you can, you know that?). Add @Yunnosch to the comment to make sure that I notice.

Comment: Note: `$length < 2` should be used to match your error message.

Comment: Tip: There's nothing inherently wrong with sorting zero or one string. It's probably better for a program that outputs its arguments in sorted order to work even if zero or one argument is provided (outputting nothing or the single argument respectively).

Comment: There is no need of loop through arguments to find the length of the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(computing)#Loops) a loop as follows:

> A loop is a sequence of statements which is specified once but which may be carried out several times in succession.

If you want to carry out certain instructions only once, they shouldn't be in a loop.<sup>[1]</sup>

```
if (@ARGV < 2) {
   die("Invalid command line arguments to program. " .
      "Please supply two or more strings to sort.\n");
}

print("@ARGV\n");    # Short for print(join(" ", @ARGV), "\n");
```

While the usage check shouldn't be in a loop, you might have a loop afterward. For example,

```
if (@ARGV < 2) {
   die("Invalid command line arguments to program. " .
      "Please supply two or more strings to sort.\n");
}

for my $arg (@ARGV) {
   print("$arg\n");
}
```

---

1. Or the loop should be exited immediately afterwards (usually through the use of `last`, `return` or `die`). For example, one might use the following code to check if an any of the items in an array matches some condition:

   ```
   my $match = 0;
   for my $item (@items) {
      if (matches($item)) {
         $match = 1;
         last;
      }
   }
   ```

   `$match = 1;` must be inside the loop (because it depends on `$item`), but since there's no point in doing `$match = 1;` more than once, we exit the loop once we find a match.

   This is not the case here.

Comment: I cannot believe that OPs problem is that simple.... But if it is, then this is nicely explained. *(mumble mumble, mustn't pout, mumble)* :-)